# PhpMyAdmin error : Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

when i try to login to phpmyadmin on xampp server this error shows up, Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
[this what appears on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrmB6.png)

i went to “C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin” to locatethe file “Config.inc.php” and tried to edit it as many solutions i have found but nothing worked for me.

here i provide you with the code i have and i hope you can help.

```
<?php

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; 

$i = 0;

$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmarktable';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

?>
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Do you have a MySQL user named 'pma' with no password?

Comment: when i tried to install symfony on xampp, it was requested that i created it besides when i checked other solutions i have found them giving a solution putting codes like this, but i can't login to phpmyadmin with a user as "root" without providing  a password even i changed $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE; also i can't login with the  controluser as pma without a password.

what do you think i chould do,to make it possible to access the phpmyadmin on xampp ?

Comment: To solve the "connection to controluser" part, I believe that you can just comment out (put // at the beginning) the lines defining controluser, controlpass and pmadb. However you will need the root password to be able to log in. Maybe this can help: https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

To remove that phpMyAdmin error, in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php` I had to

change:
`$dbuser='phpmyadmin';`
into:
`$dbuser='theuseriuse';`